# pub.dev - Packages - copyright - Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, package

It is shown everywhere how to use packages for Dart / Flutter technically.

How should a software developer comply with copyright law?
(BSD, Apache 2.0, MIT licenses are the most common.)

I have already read that some of the copyright text should be embedded.

Should the text be directly accessible in a window in the app?
 Who has experience with it?

Comment: This timely [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/fk81kq/displaying_flutters_open_source_licenses_best/) on reddit may be helpful.

Comment: Released a day ago. Thank you very much.